# How to run windows mobile device center via remote desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, remote-desktop, device-emulator-manager

I am developing mobile application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. I connect to my computer via remote desktop and my operating system is Windows Server 2012 R2. In order to test the application, I use mobile device emulator. I can run device emulator but there occurs a problem when I try to cradle the device. I found out that this is because wmdc cannot run via remote desktop. Is there any way to run wmdc via remote desktop? I searched other topics but there is no solution to this.

Note : WMDC works when I directly use the computer not with remote desktop.

Comment: This is probably because WMDC is running with elevated permissions. Remote desktop applications typically don't allow you to interact via RD with applications that are elevated. Try changing the the Group Policy options in the security settings on your server. Another option that I would try is to remote in using an account with higher permissions.

Comment: My account has administrator privilages. In group policy, what do you suggest me to change?

Comment: Here is a list of Group Policy settings: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564(v=ws.10).aspx As a start I would enable EnableUIADesktopToggle, and if you are using a remote acess other what comes preinstalled you may need to disable EnableSecureUIAPaths

Answer (score 1):

The **Windows Mobile device** center fails to connect to the Microsoft emulator when one tries to access it via `RDP`. But it works fine when used via `VNC`. Install `VNC` software such as [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/) on your server and also on your computer. Configure the `TightVNC`. From your computer try to connect to the emulator running on the server via `TightVNC client`. It just works fine.